# Pipeline not triggered upon completion of another

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

I have set up my pipelines on Azure DevOps such that pipeline_A would trigger pipeline_B after successful completion. The yaml file for pipeline_B looks like this:

```
trigger: none
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: create_function
    source: pipeline_A
    trigger: true
```

where pipeline_A is the name of the triggering pipeline as it appears in the "Pipelines" section.

I am running pipelines on the master branch, and have set the default branch for triggers to master. However, pipeline_B never gets triggered after pipeline_A finishes.

I had tried the same functionality on another pipeline on a test branch a few weeks ago and it was working. So, I'm not sure what has changed since then.

Comment: It looks like your YAML configuration is correct. Can you try to create a new pipeline and check if you still have this issue?